# Spring and Kafka: Using the same binding for Kafka Producer and Kafka Streams

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

Is this possible to use the same binding for producing messages via Kafka Producer and for sending results of stream processing by Kafka Streams?

Right now I have them separated as follows:

```java
    @Output(TOPIC_X)
    MessageChannel xOutput();

    @Output(TOPIC_X_ONE)
    KStream<?,?> xOneOutput();
```

When the first one is used by producer:

```java
channels
.xOutput()
.send(MessageBuilder
      .withPayload(x)
      .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, x.getId()).build());
```

And second one by kafka streams:

```java
@StreamListener
@SendTo(TOPIC_X_ONE)
public KStream<?,?> process(@Input(INPUT_TOPIC) KStream<String,String> inputStream){
    //ommited for clarity
}
```

And in application.yml I have:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings:
  topic-x:
    destination: mytopic
    producer:
      useNativeEncoding: true
  topic-x-one:
    destination: mytopic
    producer:
      useNativeEncoding: true
```

Is it really necessary to have them separated if they both have the same destination and both are outputs?

Comment: I am not familiar with Spring. But I am sure this information is in the documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is necessary; the bindings are handled by two different binder implementations - and a different kafka client.

Comment: The underlying target types for those bindings are different as well. One is using a `MessageChannel` for communication and the other using `KStream`. So, it is necessary to have those two separate bindings.